# Hyperlinks create line breaks

Tags: html, css

im making a website for a Youtube group i am in.

And i have alot of hyperlinks in the div #header-menu.
http://i.snag.gy/rVI8c.jpg

```css
body, html {
 width: 100%;
 background: url("/img/dirt.png");
 background-size: 2%;
 image-rendering: -webkit-optimize-contrast;
 padding-top: 0px;
 padding-left: 0px;
 font-family: Minecraftia;
}
#header {
 width: 100%;
 background-image: url("/img/header.png");
 background-repeat: repeat-x;
 background-size: 2%;
 margin-left: -8px;
 margin-top: -8px;
 height: 64px;
}
a {
 cursor: pointer;
 color: blue;
 text-decoration: none;
}
@font-face {
 font-family: Minecraftia;
 src: url("/Minecraftia-Regular.ttf");
}
#header-menu {
 width: 100%;
 height: 48px;
 line-height: 58px;
 vertical-align: middle;
 margin-left: -8px;
 padding-left: 8px;
 border-top: 1px solid black;
 border-bottom: 1px solid black;
 background: rgba(17,146,32,1);
 background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(17,146,32,1) 0%, rgba(40,128,40,1) 45%, rgba(0,82,5,1) 52%, rgba(15,123,42,1) 100%);
 background: -webkit-gradient(left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(17,146,32,1)), color-stop(45%, rgba(40,128,40,1)), color-stop(52%, rgba(0,82,5,1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(15,123,42,1)));
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(17,146,32,1) 0%, rgba(40,128,40,1) 45%, rgba(0,82,5,1) 52%, rgba(15,123,42,1) 100%);
 background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(17,146,32,1) 0%, rgba(40,128,40,1) 45%, rgba(0,82,5,1) 52%, rgba(15,123,42,1) 100%);
 background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(17,146,32,1) 0%, rgba(40,128,40,1) 45%, rgba(0,82,5,1) 52%, rgba(15,123,42,1) 100%);
 background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(17,146,32,1) 0%, rgba(40,128,40,1) 45%, rgba(0,82,5,1) 52%, rgba(15,123,42,1) 100%);
 filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#119220', endColorstr='#0f7b2a', GradientType=0 );
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
        <title>The Infected Horde</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css" type="text/css">
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="header"></div>
  <img src="/img/logo.gif" style="height: 72px; width: auto;" /><br>
  <div id="header-menu"><a id="homebtn">Home</a>&emsp;
  <a id="videosbtn">Servers We Play On</a></div>&emsp;
  <a id="aboutusbtn">About Us</a></div>&emsp;
  <a id="videosbtn">Videos</a></div>&emsp;
  <a id="contactbtn">Contact Us</a></div>&emsp;
 </body>
</html>
```

What am i doing wrong?
Sorry about the non-working images in the snippet.

Comment: The html structure is completely broken. Look at the open and closing `div` tags.

Comment: Please post a **minimal** code which reproduces the problem. 90% of the code you’ve posted is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are putting `</div>` tags without a reason, there is only one `div`, it should be :

```
<div id="header"></div>
        <img src="/img/logo.gif" style="height: 72px; width: auto;" /><br>
        <div id="header-menu"><a id="homebtn">Home</a>
        <a id="videosbtn">Servers We Play On</a>
        <a id="aboutusbtn">About Us</a>
        <a id="videosbtn">Videos</a>
        <a id="contactbtn">Contact Us</a>
         </div>
```

Use only one div i.e at the end and i would prefer using `display:inline` in the `a` tag css. Moreover here is the [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mihiruj/gj04ea7t/) and i have deleted `&emsp;` because i don't think they have any use here.

Comment: I needed emsp because it was confusing without them for the hyperlinks (they act as spaces)